# Entity Framework Setting Navigation Property by Id Issue

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, repository-pattern

I have two classes: **Owner** and **Dog**. In the **Dog** class there is a Navigation Property defined like this:

```
public class Dog {
    //Other properties
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OwnerId")]
    public virtual Owner Owner{ get; set; }
}
```

I also have the following (example) method

```
public void SetOwnerOfFirstDog(int ownerId)
{
   //var owner = context.Owners.First(e => e.Id == ownerId);

   var dog = context.Dogs.First();
   dog.OwnerId = ownerId;
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

This all works but when I later use the **same db context** and look up the same dog entity it's Owner property is null. (When I use another db context it is not null.)

However, if I uncomment the first line in the SetOwnerOfFirstDog method the Owner property will be correctly set. But of course this is an extra query to the database and I'd like to avoid it.

So my question:
How can I make sure that the Owner property is correctly filled in when I look it up after I have set the Dog's Owner by Id.

I am using lazy loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Include` to load related entities

```
public void SetOwnerOfFirstDog(int ownerId)
{       
   var dog = context.Dogs.Include(x => x.Owner).First();
   dog.OwnerId = ownerId;
   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: This works. I thought that Include was not needed with lazy loading.
If you wouldn't mind could you tell me how to include the Owner if I was creating a new Dog object in that method instead of finding an existing one?

Comment: I don't think there is a good way to do it without finding related entity. Probably you can try to do some magic with object state manager, to manually create attached entity without changes, so you wont be need any requiest to db, but I did't tryed such method